# flask-migrate won't recognize upgrade is complete

Tags: flask-migrate

I ran a `db migrate` then a `db upgrade` but the upgrade failed because one of the commands failed. (I hadn't read the migration before running it.)

I ended up in the state where `db history` recognized the upgrade had run, but `db current` still listed the previous upgrade as the HEAD.

I tried `db downgrade` then `db upgrade` and that didn't work.

How do I correct this so I can continue running migrations?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening the dev.db sqllite file and dropping the table that was correctly created by the limbo migration. Once the things changed in the latest migration were undone, I could successfully run `db upgrade` so everything was in sync again.